# PHP : create a specific array from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'd like to build an array from (among other) data stored in a MySQL Database.

**My code is the one :**

```
<?php

// STUFF ABOUT CONNECTION TO DATABASE

// Informations about host, login and so on

$query = 'SELECT * FROM maj';
$dbquery = mysql_query($query);

// Parse the dbquery

$geojson = array(
'type' => "FeatureCollection",
'features' => $feature
 );

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $feature = array(
        'location' => $row['location'], 
      'geometry' => array(
      'type' => 'Point')
        );

array_push($geojson, $feature);
}

// Return routing result
print_r($geojson);

?>
```

**I get the following array (first two elements) :**

```
Array
(
    [type] => FeatureCollection
    [features] => 
    [0] => Array
    (
        [location] => Hollywood, CA
        [geometry] => Array
            (
                [type] => Point
            )

    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [location] => Ventura County
        [geometry] => Array
            (
                [type] => Point
            )

    )

)
```

**BUT I want to get an array with that content (with 'features' having an array inside too) :**

```
Array
(
    [type] => FeatureCollection
    [features] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [location] => Hollywood, CA
                [geometry] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Point
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [location] => Ventura County
                [geometry] => Array
                    (
                        [type] => Point
                    )

            )
       )
  )
```

How could I do ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: @FuzzyTree if `$feature` is an empty string or not defined, nothing will show up there. In his code, he is just pushing on to the end of that array, which will then start at `[0]`. The other clue here is `[feature]` and `[0]` are at the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `$feature` and pass it as a reference to `$geojson`:

```
$feature = array();
$geojson = array(
  'type' => "FeatureCollection",
  'features' => &$feature
);
```

Remove the `array_push()` and just append-assign it to `$feature`:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $feature[] = array(
      'location' => $row['location'], 
      'geometry' => array(
      'type' => 'Point')
    );

   // the above is sugar for: array_push($feature, array( 'location' => ... ) );
}
```

Your call to `print_r()` should produce the results you're expecting now.

Comment: Thank you too very much for the help !!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works

```
$geojson = array(
    'type' => "FeatureCollection",
    'features' => array()
);
```

---

```
array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
```